# When automatic test navigates to Password recovery link the button won't react but manually it works fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm testing a web based application that provides a functionality for password recovery. The recovery works in such a way that the user enters their registered mail address linked to their account and the application sends out a mail to this address. The email contains a link  to the web application where the user is allowed to type in a new password, to confirm the change the user needs to press on a "Ok" button displayed on the same page. Everything in the test works perfectly fine except pressing the "Ok" button. If I navigate to it through the automatic test it won't react to neither manual or automatic mouse clicks. It only reacts to manual mouse clicks when I've browsed to the site manually. When I run the test and the test reaches the point where it has to press the button nothing happens. The button is pressed but nothing is loaded. Now if I interrupt the test and here press the button nothing happens, no matter how many times the button is pressed. However if I go back and reopen the email received and then there manually navigate to the application the button works fine.

Now I've tried to put in a Wait method to make sure that everything is loaded properly, however this had no effect. I've also tried to refresh the site when I've navigated to it (through pressing CTRL+F5). On top of this I've also copied the onclick action that is triggered once the button is pressed and typed it in the console when the test is stuck. Sadly there was no success when it was done during a automatic test but it worked fine when it was done manually.

I would love to send some piece of code but I have no access to the code in the application.

Any ideas are appreciated. Sorry for long post, and no code.

Comment: If the button is accessed via something like `this.uimap.uiouter.uimiddle.uiinner.uibutton` the do a `DrawHighLight()` on `this.uimap.uiouter` then on `...uimiddle...` and so on to find which controls can be found. You may need to re-evaluate part of the uimap with a call of `...Find()` on some control.

Comment: You can also try using fiddler to see if any web-requests are being made when clicking during the automated run and if they're the same as the requests made when you're manually clicking and running through the test. You should see a POST of some sort when clicking the "Ok" button. Also, go end to end through your test to verify that the all the same web-requests are being made manually and automatically.  I doubt this is the issue, but it may help in your debugging, maybe a verification token is being cached or something in your automated tests.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thank you for your suggestion I did try this but sadly enough it finds the button but its the action that isn't executed.

Comment: @JeffX Thank you for your suggestion I will try to debugg it and try to see what the web-requests are being sent. I will update if it works!

Comment: Just check that the `DrawHighLight` call are immediately before the `Muse.Click` that has no effect. I would also start looking at the html and other code associated with the button and clicking it, looking for anything clever that may get in the way of Coded UI.

Comment: Is it possible that when the automation navigates to the site in question, that it's taking a path that isn't populating some property (href of the link, for example) on the OK button?  The fact that you browse to it manually and it works, but if you let the automation take you there it doesn't leads me to believe that the automation is skipping some necessary step that would normally tell the button what to do OnClick().

Comment: @RyanCox This is most likely a accurate reason to why it doesn't work. I will research and debug some more and update the post if I solve the problem. Thank you for your time.